# How do I automatically number items throughout an R markdown document?

Tags: r, list, markdown, r-markdown, enumerate

I am looking for a way to automatically number examples throughout an R markdown document.

I know that automatic numbering is possible with a list, such as:

```
1. Item 1
1. Item 2
1. Item 3
```

The problem is that this will not work when the items appear in different sections, i.e.

```
# Section 1
1. Item 1
# Section 2 
1. Item 2
```

In this case, the numeration resets, so both of these Items end up with the number 1.

How do I resume numeration in R markdown across sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in mechanism for numbering across sections in markdown (or in most of the output formats that you'd be knitting your document into), but there's a hack you could try: you can define and manually increment an R variable to keep track for you.  The trade-off is that you'll lose the list formatting. But if you're OK with just numbered items, you can define an R variable in a chunk at the beginning:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
mycounter <- 0
```
````

Then use it inline (where you're writing normal text, not in a chunk) in your write-up later.  You have to increment the variable yourself:

```
`r mycounter<-mycounter+1; mycounter`. Item 1 

# Another Section

`r mycounter<-mycounter+1; mycounter`. Item 2
```

This will produce:

1. Item 1

Another Section

2. Item 2

As a general point though, numbering across sections is likely to confuse your readers.